# PHP search result highlight string not working

Tags: php, mysql, search, highlight

please i need your advice. A have a search result, i want highlight search keyword in the text.

Here i perform search (searchTest.php)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM xxxx WHERE title LIKE ? OR text1 LIKE ? OR datum LIKE ? order by (datum) desc";
try {
      $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute(["%".$_POST["search"]."%", "%".$_POST["search"]."%", "%".$_POST["search"]."%"]);
      $resultsNEW = $stmt->fetchAll();
      if (isset($_POST["ajax"])) { echo json_encode($resultsNEW); }
```

Here i handle search results, that work fine.

```
 if (isset($_POST["search"])) {
    require "searchTest.php";

    if (count($resultsNEW) > 0) { 
        foreach ($resultsNEW as $r) {
```

Here i try print the result with string replacement, but its not working

```
 echo str_replace ($r, "<span style='background-color:yellow'>$_POST[search]</span>", $r["text1"]);
```

Comment: First, look up [`str_replace()` in the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) Then you can try an place the right things in the right parameter position

Comment: It would help if you show us what the `$resultsNEW` array looks like, as you have not shown us the query

Comment: Thank you RiggsFolly, this is the answer: 
echo str_ireplace ($_POST['search'], "<span style='background-color:yellow'>$_POST[search]</span>", $r['text1']);

Comment: Please dont put answers into your question. You are allowed to answer your own questions, and accept the answers and get the reputaion point for doing so

Comment: ok thank you, i edited my question. thank for help, the php manual you provided helped me.